# sails.config.XXXX in app.js for SailsJS Framework

Tags: node.js, sails.js, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am using Sails Framework with the newrelic plugin. I am currently trying to register the app based on a flag in production.js/development.js. This is the flag in development.js:

```
    ENABLE_NEWRELIC_NODE_SERVICE: false,
```

And this is the piece of code in App.js:

```
    if (sails.config.ENABLE_NEWRELIC_NODE_SERVICE){
      require('sails-hook-newrelic/register');
    }
```

But it seems that sails.config is not accessible in app.js (I might be wrong). Is there any other way to include conditionality in App.js based on config files?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `ENABLE_NEWRELIC_NODE_SERVICE` your own flag? It's not somthing Sails provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of a Sails specific way of doing this, simply require in the config file:

```
var config = require('./sails.config') // Check the path is correct
```

Then use the flag:

```
if (config.ENABLE_NEWRELIC_NODE_SERVICE){
    require('sails-hook-newrelic/register');
}
```

Comment: This won't really solve the issue of enabling/disabling the flag properly, because the Sails config hook handles loading the appropriate config file based on the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Even though not the most correct way- but got it working!

Answer (score 1):

The `sails.config` object isn't available until Sails is actually loaded.  Looking at the code of `sails-hook-newrelic`, it's not clear to me why `register()` needs to be called so early; it seems like it could just happen as part of the hook initialization.  But, the code isn't written that way, so you're stuck on that point.  Looks like there's a [pull request](https://github.com/Kikobeats/sails-hook-newrelic/pulls) open to fix it.  In the meantime, assuming that you want to activate New Relic based on the Node environment, you can just check `process.NODE_ENV` in your `app.js`:

```
if (process.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
   require('sails-hook-newrelic/register');
}
```

Just make sure that you start your app with `NODE_ENV=development node app.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! As you mentioned it won't really solve the problem cos everytime we switch from dev to prod or any other environment- app.js would need to be modified. I had tried putting the "sails-hook-newrelic/register" later- in that case it does register but fails to actually send the data. But as you mentioned its not really a shortfall on sails' part. Thanks for the response! Really appreciate it!

Comment: As long as you use `NODE_ENV` to switch environments, you shouldn't have to modify `app.js` with this approach.